# Returning the column value even if the special character isn't present using SUBSTRING & CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL and trying to show all the data in a column before a special character like `<`.

I've used this SQL:

```
SUBSTRING(ACTIVITY.Name, 0, CHARINDEX('<', ACTIVITY.Name, 2)) AS ActivityIdentifier
```

It works absolutely fine when there is a `<` in the column, but when one isn't present I get no result. I need to be able to return the column value even if the character isn't present.

I looked at `RTRIM`, `LEFT` and `LEN` functions but as my `Activity Name` can be different lengths, they didn't seem to fit.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest fix is to append a `'<'` to the string:

```
SUBSTRING(ACTIVITY.Name, 1, CHARINDEX('<', ACTIVITY.Name + '<', 2)) as ActivityIdentifier
```

If you don't want the `'<'` in the result, then:

```
SUBSTRING(ACTIVITY.Name, 1, CHARINDEX('<', ACTIVITY.Name + '<', 2) - 1) as ActivityIdentifier
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that works. It does leave me with a < on the entries that already had this character. I'll play around and see if I can add another line to remove this.

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent too much time on this yesterday. I changed it to        SUBSTRING(ACTIVITY.Name, 0, CHARINDEX('<',ACTIVITY.Name + '<', 2)) as ActivityIdentifier and that removed the additional < where one was already present.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write a stored function that would handle this - since it's just operating on data passed in, and not doing any "hidden" data access in the background, it should be fairly well behaved in terms of performance.

Try this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.TrimSpecialChar
    (@Input NVARCHAR(500), @SpecialChar NCHAR(1))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(500);

    -- if "special char" is not found - just return input
    DECLARE @SpecCharIx INT = CHARINDEX(@SpecialChar, @Input);

    IF (@SpecCharIx = 0)
        SET @Result = @Input;
    ELSE
        SET @Result = SUBSTRING(@Input, 1, @SpecCharIx-1);

    RETURN @Result;
END
```

You can then call it like this:

```
SELECT dbo.TrimSpecialChar(N'Testinput without special characters', N'<')
```

should return back the whole input, while

```
SELECT dbo.TrimSpecialChar(N'Testinput with the < special characters', N'<')
```

would just return

```
Testinput with the
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add case expression :

```
(case when charindex('<', ACTIVITY.Name) > 0
      then SUBSTRING(ACTIVITY.Name, 1, CHARINDEX('<', ACTIVITY.Name, 2))
      else ACTIVITY.Name
 end) as ActivityIdentifier
```